# Managing open questions

Tags: feature-request

I often respond to a range of questions. Some of them are resolved in one or two steps where others take longer. I want to be able to "archive" the responses from resolved questions and only keep the responses of "open" questions visible. This way I can better track questions where the responses take longer (or the owner has not yet "accepted" the best answer). At the moment some of these questions that take longer to resolve, don't get the right follow-up since they disappear down the list of all (un-filtered) responses.